# cross platform way of hiding directories using C++

Tags: c++, filesystems, cross-platform

I created a new directory `.store` using C++ `<filesystem>` library. Although the name of the directory starts with a `.`, it is visible in File Explorer on Windows.

I learnt that it is possible with Windows API. But this works only for Windows.
Is there a way to create a hidden folder named `.store` using C++ which will work for all platforms? Or I should determine the platform and implement OS-specific APIs?

Comment: I think windows is quite different than other platforms. If depends on your definition of "hidden directory". Eg: when should it be hidden?

Comment: It should not be visible in the explorer. Also it should not be in the files listed using ls command

Comment: Then you need to call platform specific api. Since windows doesn't care about file and directory start with `.`. Also windows may display hidden file depending on its config.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, a file/folder starting with a `.` in its name is not treated any different than any other file/folder. The only way to "hide" such a file/folder is to explicitly set the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` attribute on the file/folder, such as with [`SetFileAttributes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileattributesw) or equivalent. The `<filesystem>` library will not do this for you, so yes, your code will need to detect the platform and call the appropriate API as needed.

You say that your goal is to hide the folder from File Explorer (known as Windows Explorer prior to Windows 10). Just note that Explorer has a user-configurable option to show hidden files/folders, so you can't truly hide from the user if they don't want you to.